# WordPress rewrite htaccess homepage location

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Our WP homepage url is changed. I need a rewrite in htaccess to get it done.
But I do not know how.

exiting homepage url: https://www.mysite.nl/

new homepage url: https://www.mysite.nl/nl/home/

Anyone of you a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

With RedirectMatch, you can redirect "/home" to "/"

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/home/?$ /
```

Or redirect "/" to "/home"

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /home
```